# How to codesign dmg and App inside it?

Tags: macos, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have a dmg with application inside it. I have purchased apple developer license and i have succeeded in signing the dmg using developer certificate. I checked the dmg it is signed and accepted success by Gatekeeper. I have used Sierra 10.12.5 to coding

I then copied and ran the installer and app. 
 But Running the App throws can't be opened because it is from unidentified developer.

Running the App throws unidentifed developer

[image]

```
codesign --verify --deep  --verbose=2 MyQt.app
MyQt.app: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64
```

Is it possible to codesign dmg and recursively all content inside including the App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sign .app with `Developer ID` certificate 
You can generate it at developer.apple.com if you are a Team

`codesign --force --deep -s DeveloperIDCertificate --keychain pathToKeychain YourApp.app`

`--force` will replica your previous signature

`--deep` will recursively sign your content

`-s DeveloperIDCertificate` will sign app by identity. It should be like this: `-s 123C3FF2VA`

`--keychain` is argument for keychain database folder, for Sierra usually it's `/Users/username/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db`

Comment: Andrew, i compiled the dmg in ubuntu so i cannot extract .App from the dmg to sign. Is there a way?

Comment: pbu did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Trying this gives me: “‹id›: no identity found”. It works if I use a self-signed certificate instead of the Developer ID certificate but that is obviously not a solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, please, check identity. Also you should have DeveloperID certificate in keychain with private part.

Comment: @AndrewVergunov Hmm I think that’s the issue: I have the certificate in the keychain but I suspect it’s missing the private key component. Not sure how that could happen (I got the .cer file from a colleague who’s responsible for the Apple Dev ID in our organisation).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think your colleague should export certificate with private part.

Comment: @AndrewVergunov Yes indeed. In hindsight it’s perfectly obvious.

Comment: @AndrewVergunov Do I have to sign the .app before to create the dmg and sign the dmg after or is it fine to create the .app, create the dmg and finally sign the two files separately ?

Comment: @Damien I'm almost sure that you should sign .app firstly.